# Controlling The firefox launching port

Tags: java, firefox, webdriver

I am a user of selenium webdriver and I am currently running parallel tests in my automation.I  have come to understand that firefox launches from port 7054 when first launching via webdriver.I am running 10 tests at a time and I was wondering if there was some way I could control the port on which firefox browser would be launched example if I wish to launch it from port 7056 when i know another is launching from 7054. Thanks in adavnce

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in theory you could do it with `.setPreference(PORT_PREFERENCE, portNumber)` on the `FirefoxDriver`, but in reality you can't change the port due to [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5172) that causes the default port to always override the port preference.

Unless they fixed it in the past 2 months it seems like you're out of luck; although if you are in a bind, you can grab the Selenium source and apply the fix detailed in that bug report on your own as a temporary workaround.

However, if you are running your tests from different *processes*, you should be able to specify `-Dwebdriver.firefox.port=1234` on the command line to change the port for that particular instance of your program. I have not tried it, [but the documentation shows that property](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver).